# connecting gmail to a laravel application: send and receive emails from withing the app

Tags: laravel, api, gmail

I'm trying to connect gmail to a laravel application so I can send and receive emails from withing the app just like this image: https://ibb.co/1QkDTTh.
I just don't have any idea how to start, so if any of you have a general idea on how this could be done please tell me. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this
add the following code in .env file and then go to gmail security(https://myaccount.google.com/security) and then turn on less secure apps

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=your gmail Id
MAIL_PASSWORD=your gmail password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME=test
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you should allow less secure app to use your google account.
This can be done in your [google account](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

Then you have to add your parameters to your `config/mail.php` file or in the .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=ENTER_YOUR_GMAIL_USERNAME
MAIL_PASSWORD=ENTER_YOUR_GMAIL_PASSWORD
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

now you can add your php code to send emails using your google account

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
//...
$to_name = 'TO_NAME';
$to_email = 'TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS';
$data = array('name'=>"Sam Jose", "body" => "Test mail");

Mail::send('emails.mail', $data, function($message) use ($to_name, $to_email) {
    $message->to($to_email, $to_name)
            ->from('FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS','Artisans Web')
            ->subject('Artisans Web Testing Mail');
    ;
});
```

your view should be `resources/views/emails/mail.blade.php`

```
Hi <strong>{{ $name }}</strong>,

<p>{{ $body }}</p>
```

That's it